# Make a temporary record, that deletes itself after 24 hours?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am making a system where a user can get a reward code, but only every 24 hours. I want to insert a record into a MySQL database, that deletes itself 24 hours after being added. This way I can use mysql_num_rows to see if the row is there.

How would I make a mysql row that deletes itself after 24 hours? Or is there an alternative to this, where I can check if specific information has already been used in the past 24 hours?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about adding an `expiration` column to the table, and checking that to see if the code is still valid? Additionally, add a `redeemed` column, where you can mark whether a code has been used.

Comment: That's a good idea. I hadn't thought of that, probably would be more efficient than deleting the record after 24 hours.

Comment: I'd go for something like this.  If you delete records out of your table, you lose the ability to go back and look at any historical data.

Comment: Yeah, what I was doing was putting just the information needed to check if they had already done it in another table, while still keeping the rest of the data in a separate table, but this is what I'm going to do.

Comment: sounds like you already have a good solution here...all I would add is that for stuff like this I always add an 'active' field as well that is just a boolean. That way you can inactivate a reward whenever you want for whatever reason with a simple update.